# XPages fullCalendar is not a function

Tags: jquery, dojo, fullcalendar, xpages

Hello I need to use this FullCalendar Scheduler [Example Scheduler Code](http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.2.0/demos/vertical-resource-view.html)  (if you open the source code of example page is very simple to undestard)

So in my XPages I have created an XPages with code :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">



    <xp:div styleClass="calendarcss " id="calendar">

    </xp:div>


    <xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[$(function() { // document ready
        var x=x$("#{id:calendar}");
        x.fullCalendar({
            defaultView: 'agendaDay',
            defaultDate: '2016-01-07',
            editable: true,
            selectable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'agendaDay,agendaTwoDay,agendaWeek,month'
            },
            views: {
                agendaTwoDay: {
                    type: 'agenda',
                    duration: { days: 2 },
                    // views that are more than a day will NOT do this behavior by default
                    // so, we need to explicitly enable it
                    groupByResource: true
                    //// uncomment this line to group by day FIRST with resources underneath
                    //groupByDateAndResource: true
                }
            },
            //// uncomment this line to hide the all-day slot
            //allDaySlot: false,
            resources: [
                { id: 'a', title: 'Room A' },
                { id: 'b', title: 'Room B', eventColor: 'green' },
                { id: 'c', title: 'Room C', eventColor: 'orange' },
                { id: 'd', title: 'Room D', eventColor: 'red' }
            ],
            events: [
                { id: '1', resourceId: 'a', start: '2016-01-06', end: '2016-01-08', title: 'event 1' },
                { id: '2', resourceId: 'a', start: '2016-01-07T09:00:00', end: '2016-01-07T14:00:00', title: 'event 2' },
                { id: '3', resourceId: 'b', start: '2016-01-07T12:00:00', end: '2016-01-08T06:00:00', title: 'event 3' },
                { id: '4', resourceId: 'c', start: '2016-01-07T07:30:00', end: '2016-01-07T09:30:00', title: 'event 4' },
                { id: '5', resourceId: 'd', start: '2016-01-07T10:00:00', end: '2016-01-07T15:00:00', title: 'event 5' }
            ],
            select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view, resource) {
                console.log(
                    'select',
                    start.format(),
                    end.format(),
                    resource ? resource.id : '(no resource)'
                );
            },
            dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view, resource) {
                console.log(
                    'dayClick',
                    date.format(),
                    resource ? resource.id : '(no resource)'
                );
            }
        });

    });]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:scriptBlock>
</xp:view>
```

All work corretly only if I disable Dojo with **xsp.client.script.libraries=none**

If I remove the above line the firebug console show me this error in the 3 lines of my **scriptBlock**:

> fullCalendar is not a function

Some idea to fix and enable corretly dojo library?

Comment: Which domino server version do you use? Futhermore how and where you include your `jquery` and `fullCalendar` libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok the problem is the AMD Loader ...
The solution was insert the code before DOJO...with this statement

```
<xp:this.properties>
        <xp:parameter name="xsp.resources.aggregate" value="true" />
    </xp:this.properties>    
<xp:this.resources>
        <xp:headTag tagName="script">
             <xp:this.attributes>
                 <xp:parameter name="type" value="text/javascript" />
                 <xp:parameter name="src" value="jquery-2.1.4.min.js" />
             </xp:this.attributes>
         </xp:headTag>
         <xp:headTag tagName="script">
             <xp:this.attributes>
                 <xp:parameter name="type" value="text/javascript" />
                 <xp:parameter name="src" value="moment.min.js" />
             </xp:this.attributes>
         </xp:headTag>
        <xp:headTag tagName="script">
             <xp:this.attributes>
                 <xp:parameter name="type" value="text/javascript" />
                 <xp:parameter name="src" value="fullcalendar.min.js" />
             </xp:this.attributes>
         </xp:headTag>
          <xp:headTag tagName="script">
             <xp:this.attributes>
                 <xp:parameter name="type" value="text/javascript" />
                 <xp:parameter name="src" value="scheduler.min.js" />
             </xp:this.attributes>
         </xp:headTag>
    </xp:this.resources>
```

Comment: Hi Daniele Grillo , I have done the same thing as you have explained and my issue is also same but it is not working for me, Is there any other thing to do?

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be the AMD hack from Ferry: https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=hack-to-use-jquery-amd-widgets-and-dojo-together

Comment: Oliver: the above solution don't work when compressed option xpages resources (js and css) is enabled. So I need to use Sven solution. Thanks!